# What does "/" (slash) mean in the picture below?

Tags: jeppesen, symbology, aeronautical-charts, takeoff-minimums

What does the slash mark between R/V mean? Should both RVR and visibility be at least 400m, or should only one of the two values be at least 400m (ie the other could be lower)? If summarized to simplify, does the "/" sign mean "or" or "and"? The table also uses the symbol "&" in the RL & RCLM expression which means "and". The term "or" is also used for RL or RCLM. But I don't know what "/" (slash) means from these two.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the Introduction to Jeppesen Navigation Charts, it means that RVR and meteorological visibility are equivalent here:

> [image: Jeppesen Approach Chart Legend]
>
> **3 —** Visibility values in meters are labeled with an "m" while values in
> kilometers are labeled with a "km". When an RVR value is not
> equivalent to the associated meteorological visibility, both are shown
> and labeled "R" and "V".’ When RVR and MET VIS are equivalent,
> the visibility is shown once, ’and labeled as R/V, meaning either
> RVR or MET VIS.